# Kusto functions migration to upper environment

Tags: azure-data-explorer, adx

I have several functions on the dev ADX environment. Now I need to migrate all of them into upper environment. Is there any handy commands to export all available functions from one environment to another. I tried to export all functions as csv after running `.show functions` command. But could not find any way to import this csv file to another environment.

Comment: Hi @Justin, does the answer below help? If yes, please accept it (it's the stackoverflow way of saying 'thanks'). If you're missing any info, please add a comment elaborating what you're missing. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Slavik i was away, now I have accepted the answer. I have exported all the table schema, ingestion policies and queries with the help of the command you shared. Then i used this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script#example and imported all of them together. Saved a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command will produce you a csl script that will recreate all your tables, functions etc.: `.show database schema as csl script` - just go over its output and take only what you need.

Comment: Once after exporting use the example here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script#example to import all of them together to the new environment